# Identifying of Vertical Datum from Metadata

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, metadata, datum

I have been working with the DEM of South Carolina and I am not able to see from the metadata what is the vertical of the DEM.

How do I identify the vertical datum from the attached screenshot of the metadata?

[image: The attached image is a screenshot of the metadata]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! It seems like it doesn't have a defined vertical datum.

Comment: Pictures of text are less than optimal, since they are not legible on all devices, and not free-text searchable. Datasets based on Clarke 1866 are immediately suspect, because that was the default datum used by Arc/Info before systematic projection files were common. You should probably research the history of this metadata before accepting it at face value, and should definitely try to test for validity.

Comment: What version of Arc are you using? I seem to recall that Arc desktop was not "vertical-datum aware" [my phraseology] until 10.4.1 or possibly 10.6.1.  Perhaps the lack of a vertical datum listing is due to your version of Arc.

Comment: What is the source of this DEM that you have?  Is it a USGS 10 meter DEM?  If so, see here https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-are-projection-horizontal-and-vertical-datum-and-resolution-3d-elevation-program-3dep?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products.

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions! I got the DEM from the department of natural resource website of south Carolina